# how to auto update collection using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-replica-set

I want to auto update `isActive` field to false if `timing.from` is less than Date.now() and then filter out all those docs whose isActive is false.
This can be achieved by mongodb-replica-sets. But it's not auto updating.
Here is my code:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  timing: {
    from: Date,
    to: Date,
  }, 
  isActive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
});
const Concerts = mongoose.model("Concerts", schema);
const pipeline = [
  { $match: { "timing.from": { $lt: Date.now() } } },
  { $set: { isActive: false } },
];

Concerts.watch(pipeline).on("change", (data) => console.log(data));
```

And if you could also suggest how to filter on the basis of `isActive` on every find(). Thank you for your efforts.